# how to highlights specific dates in CalendarView in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calendar, calendarview

i have tried most things online from custom calendar views to dependencies but they all lead to being outdated and not usable for android studio in its latest version.

does anyone know how to achieve this? I have tried mCalendarView, SunDeepK CalendarView and material-calendar view, but to no avail..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setCustomResourceForDates() {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        //highlighlighting the holidays in a month taking the static dates
        ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
        dates.add("02-08-2015");
        dates.add("22-08-2015");
        dates.add("17-09-2015");
        dates.add("25-09-2015");
        dates.add("27-09-2015");
        dates.add("13-10-2015");
        dates.add("22-10-2015");
        SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        for (int i = 1; i < dates.size(); i++) {
            inputString2 = dates.get(i);
            inputString1 = myFormat.format(date);

            try {
                //Converting String format to date format
                date1 = myFormat.parse(inputString1);
                date2 = myFormat.parse(inputString2);
                //Calculating number of days from two dates
                long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
                long datee = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
                //Converting long type to int type
                day = (int) datee;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, day);
            holidayDay = cal.getTime();
            colors();

        }
    }

    public void colors() {
        if (caldroidFragment != null) {
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDate(R.color.green,
                    holidayDay);
            caldroidFragment.setTextColorForDate(R.color.white, holidayDay);
        }
    }
}
```

call  `setCustomResourceForDates();` on `onCreate` method (in `Caldroid` Calendar

you can find it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32601769/20137896

Comment: what is caldroidFragment?